# Formatting text in Description field?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Is there a way to format any of the text in the 'Description' field of the DESCRIPTION file in an R package?  I'd like to add emphasize (e.g. italicize) a few of the words; but, it's not critical, so I don't want to change the encoding.

Perhaps this is impossible, but I can't find any mention of it besides briefly in the [Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file).  Anyway, here's what has been unsuccessful for me...

**bold**:

- Surrounding text with `**`
- Text inside `\textbf{}` (which shows up as `\{}textbf{}`)

*italics*:

- Surrounding text with `__` (double underscore)
- Text inside `\textit{}` (which also shows up as `\{}textit{}`)

Comment: Have a look at section 2.3 of [R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Marking-text) though I don't know 100% if these commands work.

Comment: Hmm this does not work.

Comment: Can you say what you're aiming for here? As far as I can see the DESCRIPTION file is really a "text-only" object ... I would be inclined to use a common conventions like * or _ and trust that readers would understand it.  Given that the R console doesn't typically do any variation in letter type, and the only place I know of where DESCRIPTION is viewed is in `help(package="foo")`, I'm having trouble seeing the point (I guess it's in the PDF version of the manual too -- maybe that's what you care about?)

Comment: I recognize that it's intended to be text-only (it says that plainly in the manual), but why should it be that way?  That's mostly a rhetorical question, but it just seemed odd that I couldn't use the commands that @Tyler Rinker points out, especially since the description gets typeset with the rest of the Rd files.